# How to determine the visibility of a webView object

Tags: android, android-espresso

In a normal test statement i can do

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).check(isDisplayed());
```

Inside a webview i can't do

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID,"listItem0")).check(isDisplayed())
```

does anyone know how to do a visibility check on a webview element?

Comment: Please do you have an answer to this?